# Alternative computation of $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x^4)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

I know how to prove that,

$\displaystyle K=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x^4)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{9}{4}\pi\ln^2 2+\frac{7}{48}\pi^3-12G\ln 2$

(see: [Closed form for the following integrals $ 1)\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)\ln (1+x^2)}{1+x^2} \; dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644467/closed-form-for-the-following-integrals-1-int-01-frac-ln1-x2-ln-1x2) )

But, i'm searching for an alternative proof **using Beta function of Euler**

My attempts:

$\displaystyle K=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln^2(1-x^4)}{1-x^4}-\frac{x^2\ln^2(1-x^4)}{1-x^4}\right)\,dx$

But,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x^4)}{1-x^4}\,dx$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x^2\ln^2(1-x^4)}{1-x^4}\,dx$ do not converge.

Second attempt,

$\displaystyle K=\frac{1}{48}\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{x}-3\right)x^{-\frac{7}{4}}\ln^3(1-x)\,dx$

But, for example, if $s\geq 0$,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{-\frac{7}{4}}(1-x)^s\,dx$

does not converge.

Third attempt,

$\displaystyle K=-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\left(\sqrt{1-x}-1\right)\ln^2 x}{x\left(1-x\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\,dx$

But,
$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{x\left(1-x\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\,dx$

does not converge.

Comment: Try applying a parameter $s$ to evaluate the divergent integrals then take the limit at the end. It will be a tedious approach.

Comment: You're right, i need a second parameter.

Comment: The Catalan's constant appears in $\psi_1(1/4)$ so that might work.